# Problema con permisos en Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que permite subir una foto de perfil. Para ello accedo a la galería mediante un intent.

El problema viene con los permisos de lectura, los solucioné, en parte, incluyendo en el manifest lo siguiente:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

En un smartphone con Android Lollipop se soluciona el problema, pero al correr la aplicación en un smartphone con Android Marshmallow sigue apareciendo el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/file/38720 from pid=20457, uid=10195 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

Por lo que he leído y poco que he entendido no se puede hacer nada desde el manifest, si no que hay que añadir código en la propia actividad, aquí es donde me pierdo totalmente.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde `Marshmallow` hay que solicitar los privilegios en Runtime al usuario. Te doy un ejemplo (en este caso para telefono y SMS):

```
static final String[] PHONE_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS};
static final String[] SMS_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
        Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS};
static final int PHONE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST=0;
static final int SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST=1;


public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    // más código de onCreate

    if (!hasPhonePermissions()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,PHONE_PERMISSIONS,PHONE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    } else if (!hasSmsPermissions()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,SMS_PERMISSIONS,SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case PHONE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:
            // filter logic
            if (!hasSmsPermissions()) ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,SMS_PERMISSIONS,SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
            for (int i=0;i<permissions.length;i++){
                Log.d("Permission: ",String.format("Phone %d) granted %b", i+1,grantResults[i]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ));
            }
            break;
        case SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:
            for (int i=0;i<permissions.length;i++){
                // reaccionar a permiso o rechazo
                Log.d("Permission: ",String.format("Sms %d) granted %b", i+1,grantResults[i]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ));
            }
            break;
    }
}

private boolean hasPhonePermissions(){
    boolean hp=true;
    hp = hp && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    hp = hp && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    hp = hp && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    return hp;
}

private boolean hasSmsPermissions(){
    boolean hp=true;
    hp = hp && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    hp = hp && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    hp = hp && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    return hp;
}
```

En tu caso tienes que procesar `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Concreto:

```
boolean priv = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

if (!priv){
    String[] privilegios = { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, privilegios,0);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int rc, @NonNull String[] privilegios, @NonNull int[]resultados){
     // evaluar si se obtuvo el privilegio
}
```